# How do you make the raspberry pi ask you a question?

Tags: python

I want to make my raspberry pi ask me a question, but not with sound, with text. I learned how to do it a while ago, but I forgot.

Comment: How to put this. Mmmh. This question really is too non-specific to get many helpful answers. What is it you want to do? Do you want to write a program to fulfil that task? If so what programming/scripting language do you know or want to use? Or do you want to install a ready program to do your bidding? If so what operating system do you run on your RPi?

Answer (score 1):

Like @Ghanima said in the comments, this question is a bit too non-specific and I'm not sure exactly what you want. However, I think I can provide a basic answer.

---

Python is the language of choice for the Raspberry Pi (the Pi in the name is a take on Python) and comes pre-installed on Raspbian, so the example I'll provide will be in Python.

This will be a *very* basic Q/A Python script. If you want more in depth features and more control, I suggest checking out [Learn Python.org](http://learnpython.org/), [Learn Python the Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/), or [Codecademy's Python Course](http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/python).

## Teh Codez

A basic Q/A script written in Python 3.3, you can run it via `python3 [YOURFILENAMEHERE].py`

```
print("Hey there!")
going = input("How's it going? ")
print ("Oh that's great! It's going",going,"for me too")
age = input("How old are you? ")
print ("Really?",age,"is a great age!")
print ("Okay, bye for now!")
```

## Explanation:

You'll notice `print` comes up a lot in this script, it starts 4 of the 6 lines. That's the statement, or keyword, for **print** ing something to the screen. You'll also notice that whatever's within the area between the Parenthesis is printed.

However, in the case of `print ("Oh that's great! It's going",going,"for me too")` and `print ("Really?",age,"is a great age!")`, you'll notice the quotation marks end, and are followed by a comma, then a variable (`going` or `age` respectively.) Like this: `going",going,"for`.

This is one way, in Python, you can print data that a variable is holding. The commas insert a space while the variable tells what to print.

And that brings me to the next point, variables. In the `going = input("How's it going? ")` and `age = input("How old are you? ")` lines, you'll notice a word, then an equals sign (=), then input.

The first word (`going` or `age` respectively) is the variable that the input statement will put its input in. In simpler terms, the first word stores what you give the computer when it asks. If you enter `good!` for the first question, the computer will store `good!` in the `going` variable.

---

That's all I'm going to share, I don't want to give a full lesson on Python code within the bounds of a Stack Exchange answer. Again, if you want to learn more about Python, follow those links I gave above.

Hope this helped!